# Linked Server Between SQL Server and iSeries is rounding decimals

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, iseries

We just set up a new SQL Server 2008 database, and I got the link set up between our server and an iSeries As400 server that we get some of our data from.

The problem I'm having is that it is rounding down any floating numbers, which is a pain because we're working with dollar amounts a lot of the time.

```
select * FROM openquery(NADS, 'select CMD, 1.23 Type from CREDD')
```

On our older server this returns the CMD column, and a column called Type with 1.23 all the way down. On the new server type is just 1.00

So far as I can tell, the link part is set up the same. The IBM i Access for Windows ODBC Setup is mostly the same, but there are some differences between versions that I'm not sure about.

Edit:
In case it matters, For the provider I'm using Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers

Edit2:

provider options are the same
[image: provider options are the same]

Linked Server properties:
[image]

iSeries Access for windows ODBC setup appears to be the same
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what it is on the iSeries side. I'm assuming some kind of float. I'm just doing a select * on my side, so unless openquery is converting the data it should be the same...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out!!

Apparently we didn't have the latest service pack installed. We had to install the 64bit version of the service pack (32bit version failed to install), and when it finished the decimal numbers were coming across.

In case anyone was wondering:
We're using "IBM iAccess for Windows 7.1 (07.01.0800) (64bit)" and using "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers" as the linked server sql driver.

Seeing as I just ran into this problem again and had to hunt down the service pack again, here is the link to the service pack download page, so that in a few years when I run into this problem again I will find it easier...

http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows_sp.html

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple: let AS400 convert the value in float because implicit conversion applied by the iSeries provider fails almost everytime. 
So, very simply:

```
select * FROM openquery(NADS, 'select CMD, cast(1.23 as float) Type from CREDD')
```

In this way all works fine: 1.23 will be float in Sql Server too